# how to customize receive-code and authorize page in Apigility

Tags: api, rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

am request this url

http://xxxxxx/mobileapi/public/oauthtest/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=userapi&redirect_uri=./receivecode&state=xyz

and show this page

image in that link:https://www.apigility.org/apigility-documentation/img/auth-oauth2-authorize.png

but i want only **return json value** with *token*

Answer (score 0):

You should do some reading in the [ZF-OAuth documentation](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2).
To request a token you send a `POST` request with user credentials and client id to the `oauth` endpoint:

So for example a `POST` request to your base url for `/oauth` with the following `json` data:

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "password": "1234abcd",
    "username": "john.doe@example.com",
    "client_id": "MyClient"
}
```

Comment: I quote from your question: *"but i want only return json value with token"*.